# AWS Athena: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-athena

I am running a very large query in AWS athena from an EC2 machine. I have tested my code locally with smaller datasets without any issues. The code is very similar to the [aws example code on github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/java/example_code/athena/src/main/java/aws/example/athena). I have increased the query quota to a suitable duration so I don't believe it is a typical timeout, I would also expect a different error message for that (maybe it is some timeout though?). I have also made sure to configure TLSv1.2 and SSLv3 on my ec2 machine. Any ideas?

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.doInvoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:2377)
    at com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:2344)
    at com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.invoke(AmazonAthenaClient.java:2333)
    at com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.executeGetQueryResults(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1159)
    at com.amazonaws.services.athena.AmazonAthenaClient.getQueryResults(AmazonAthenaClient.java:1128)
    at org.myproject.di.AthenaInput.processResultRows(AthenaInput.java:113)
    at org.myproject.di.AthenaInput.processRow(AthenaInput.java:74)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.writeTo(BasicHttpEntity.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy.writeTo(ResponseEntityProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity.<init>(BufferedHttpEntity.java:62)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1338)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:596)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.writeTo(BasicHttpEntity.java:116)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: If it is being caused by the query being too complex, have you looked at other ways to store the data or other ways to write the query so that it is more efficient? Worst case, you might need to break the query into smaller portions that generate temporary tables used by additional queries.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Unfortunately I need to use Athena, I've tried avro and parquet files and have the same issue. Breaking the query into smaller portions might be what I have to do thanks.

Comment: I typically convert my files to Snappy-compressed, partitioned Parquet files. It runs a lot faster due to the columnar format and it costs a lot less. See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)